# View file is missing when outputting CSV

Tags: cakephp, csv, routes

I'm using CakePHP 2.x, and running it locally on IIS. I'm following the tutorial on [Exporting data to CSV the CakePHP way](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/jeroendenhaan/2010/04/23/exporting-data-to-csv-the-cakephp-way), and I'm getting an error.

The URL I'm entering is like: `http://myproject.localhost/territory/spreadsheet.csv`

I have `Router::parseExtensions('csv');` as the first thing in `app\Config\routes.php`

Here's my controller:

`class TerritoryController extends AppController
{
    public $useTable = 'ezrep_territory';

```
public $paginate = array('limit' => 50);

public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->deny('index');
}

public function Index()
{
    // ... snip ...
}

public function Spreadsheet()
{
    $data = $this->Territory->find(
        'all',
        array(
            'conditions' => array('Territory.ez' => $this->ez),
            'fields' => array('territory','terrcode','terrdesc'),
            'contain' => false
    ));
    $headers = array(
        'Territory'=>array(
            'territory' => 'Territory ID',
            'terrcode' => 'Terr Code',
            'terrdesc' => 'Terr Desc'
        )
    );

    array_unshift($data,$headers);
    $this->set(compact('data'));
}
```

}
`

In `app\View\Layouts\csv`, I have a file `default.ctp`:

`<?php
    echo $content_for_layout;
?>`

And in `app\View\Territory`, I have a file `spreadsheet.ctp`:

```
// Loop through the data array
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    // Loop through every value in a row
    foreach ($row['Territory'] as &$value)
    {
        // Apply opening and closing text delimiters to every value
        $value = "\"".$value."\"";
    }
    // Echo all values in a row comma separated
    echo implode(",",$row['Territory'])."\n";
}
```

When I go to `http://myproject.localhost/territory/spreadsheet.csv`, I get a page that appears to be rendered through the `app\View\Layouts\default.ctp` with an error:

`View file &quot;C:\zproj\ezrep40\app\View\Territory\csv\spreadsheet.ctp&quot; is missing.`
and
`Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not right

> And in app\View\Territory, I have a file spreadsheet.ctp:

you'll need to place also the view, and not just the layout, in a sub directory named after the extension:

> app\View\Territory\csv\spreadsheet.ctp